# Set min and max zoom level to include a specific layer in GeoServer vector tiles

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, vector-tiles

GeoServer has the capability of creating vector tiles in formats such as GeoJSON, TopoJSON or PBF from different kinds of data stores. In a test application, there is a layer group of an area which has been published in PBF format as vector tiles. The problem is I want the map to include some layers in a particular zoom level but the vector tiles contain these layers in higher zoom level which are not required. I know in GWC home page there are options to determine start and end zoom level of seeding cache tiles, but can we drop some layers in A to B zoom levels of produced PBF files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Associate them with a SLD style that disables rendendering at the desired scale denominators. In GeoServer the PBF contents are driven by the default style, both in terms of scale dependencies and filters (but of course, not symbolizers). This is done so that you can get a similar output from server side rendering (PNG Output) and client side rendering (PBF + client side style).

Comment: As styling of PBF files happens in the client side, using SLD min and max scale denominator effects the outputs?

Comment: Yes, the server SLD is your filtering mechanism.