# Improving the performance of a map showing millions of point - Vector Tiles vs WebGL

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles, webgl

I am trying to display a map with millions of points with OpenLayers.
I published a Multipoint shapefile as Vector Tile service with GeoServer.

When I display the map at a low scale, it takes some seconds to render the point dataset. For high zoom everything is fine.

I thought using vector tiles would have been fine for this situation, but apparently having to request so many geometries still is not the best.

So, after some research, I think I am left with these two options, which one would you suggest?

**OPTION 1**

Stick with vector tiles and improve the performance by

1. adding a filter server-side using a SLD file as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/313478/9518) to limit somehow the number of geometries required for low scales.
2. reduce the number of points at low scales using some algorithm (actually, I don't know if this is feasible with GeoWebCache, but it seems to be with tippecanoe, although I would need a completely different environment for this).

**OPTION 2**

Use WebGL rendering as I read that it is good for rendering large dataset ([OpenLayers example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/filter-points-webgl.html?q=style)).

Comment: or use a WMTS service for low scale - millions of points are unusable at that scale so a picture is fine

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton for your comment. I would probably need to do some sort of on the fly filtering on this map regardless of the scale (e.g. controlling the features to display using the only attribute I have in the vectors, changing the colors, etc.). I don't think I can do that with WMTS, but I might be wrong. Anyway, are you aware of some sort of algorithm to reduce the amount of points for lower scales in GWC?

Comment: showing millions of points may not have many utilities but at least from the performance side using an image cache service like WMTS will render quickly after the initial cache at each scale level has been saved on the server side

Comment: Thanks @artwork21. I know a raster tile service would be quicker, but I am still trying to figure out a way to stick with vectors. One way of course would be to aggregate the points at lower scales, but I still don't know how to dot it with GWC. With tippecanoe I see it is feasible (as shown in [this article](https://blog.mapbox.com/mapping-extremely-dense-point-data-with-vector-tiles-4052eb409e78)). That would be great, but I would need to abandon GeoServer in this case, which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Even better, to stick with geoserver I am gonna try [Rendering Transformations](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html) with SLD. Will report my finding back.

Comment: With millions of points, you are likely using a database. You could do some clustering in the DB, saving the output to materialized view for example, and then serving this data "as usual".

Comment: I would use a scale dependent layer group and use aggressively filtered source data for low zooms. At that scale you really need just to see that there is some data. You could for example select all features with IDs ending with ...000 and millions are reduced into thousands.

Comment: @user30184 that is definitely my goal.I am going to try reducing the number of points for lower scale with tippecanoe as explained [here](https://blog.mapbox.com/mapping-extremely-dense-point-data-with-vector-tiles-4052eb409e78). This way I could get the benefit of dynamic filtering/styling of the vectors plus the performance of the tiles. I also liked the JGH suggestion although I prefer not to get too far from my initial approach. Will keep you up to date with my findings as soon as I test. Thank you.

Comment: @user30184 anyway, how would you filter a vector tile based on zoom level? Are you talking about using SLD to filter?

Comment: I ended up using the mapbox-gl-js library to exploit the quick rendering of webgl and the vector tiles at the same time. So both my options. The result is amazing. Software I used: Tippecanoe to create the vector tiles, tileserver-gl to serve them and openlayers 6 + mapbox-gl-js library to display them. Code adapted from here: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-layer.html